# spritekitでのノードのランダムな動き

Tags: ios, spritekit

spritekitで初歩的な簡単なゲームの作成中です。
８つのノードを作成し、それぞれがバラバラのタイミングで動き出してほしいのですが、なかなかうまくいきません。
この８つのノードがランダムにバラバラのタイミングで動き出すためにはどのような修正を加えればよいでしょうか？ご回答のほう、よろしくお願いします。

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var moveToAction :SKAction!

    // 衝突に使うBitMask.
    let msCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let ckCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //        画像からスプライトを作成する
        let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        //        サイズプロパティでサイズを設定
        mySprite.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        //        ポジションプロパティで設定
        // 画像の描画場所を指定.
        mySprite.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 100)


        addChild(mySprite)


//        ノード８つをつくります
        let mySprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite2.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite2.position  = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 500)
        addChild(mySprite2)

        let mySprite3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite3.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite3.position  = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(mySprite3)

        let mySprite4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite4.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite4.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite4)

        let mySprite5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite5.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite5.position  = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite5)

        let mySprite6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite6.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite6.position  = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite6)

        let mySprite7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite7.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite7.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 500)
        addChild(mySprite7)

        let mySprite8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite8.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite8.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0)
        addChild(mySprite8)

        //        回転の動きをいれる
        let action1 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(360 * M_PI / 180), duration: 1)
        let action3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action1)

//        指定した位置まで移動させる
        let action4 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 512, y: 380), duration: 1)

        //        複数の動きを同時に処理
        let actionx = SKAction.group([action1,action3,action4])

//        それぞれの出現時間を変えたい
        let action2y = SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0,withRange: 3.0)
        let action2x = SKAction.group([actionx,action2y])

        let action3y = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0,withRange: 2.0)
        let action3x = SKAction.group([actionx,action3y])

        let action4y = SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0,withRange: 3.0)
        let action4x = SKAction.group([actionx,action4y])

        let action5y = SKAction.waitForDuration(10.0,withRange: 2.0)
        let action5x = SKAction.group([actionx,action5y])

        let action6y = SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0,withRange: 2.0)
        let action6x = SKAction.group([actionx,action6y])

        let action7y = SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0,withRange: 2.0)
        let action7x = SKAction.group([actionx,action7y])

        let action8y = SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0,withRange: 2.0)
        let action8x = SKAction.group([actionx,action8y])

        //        実行します
        mySprite.runAction(actionx)
        mySprite2.runAction(action2x)
        mySprite3.runAction(action3x)
        mySprite4.runAction(action4x)
        mySprite5.runAction(action5x)
        mySprite6.runAction(action6x)
        mySprite7.runAction(action7x)
        mySprite8.runAction(action8x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKAction`の複数のアクションを複合したアクションを作るのに、ふたつのメソッドが用意されています。

1. `class func group(_ actions: [SKAction]) -> SKAction`
   これは、複数のアクションを同時に実行します。たとえばノードが回転しながら、大きくなるというようなアニメーションになります。
2. `class func sequence(_ actions: [SKAction]) -> SKAction`
   こちらは、ひとつのアクションの実行が完了してから、つぎのアクションを開始するという動きになります。

---

```
// 複数の動きを同時に処理
let actionx = SKAction.group([action1,action3,action4])

// それぞれの出現時間を変えたい
let action2y = SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0,withRange: 3.0)
let action2x = SKAction.group([actionx,action2y])
```

動作するアクションと、待ち時間を挿入するアクションを同時に実行しています。それでは待ち時間を入れる意味がありません。

```
let action2x = SKAction.sequence([action2y, actionx])
```

こう修正すれば、3秒待ってからアニメーションが始まるはずです。（アクションの実行は、配列のインデックスの順番になります。あたりまえですが、念押しで書いておきます）
ほかのノードのアクションも同様です。

Comment: 丁寧に念押しまでありがとうございます。
お手数ですが、もしactionの実行の順番までランダムするには、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？御回答の方、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `SKAction.waitForDuration(a, withRange: b)`の、`b`の値を適切に与えられれば、期待どおりの結果になるでしょう。時間の幅が、現状の2秒、ないし3秒では、ちょっとランダム感が乏しくなるかなという印象を受けます。